# How to put a variable in a like statement in vba?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm trying to get data from a db access using sql statement Like with a variable

The variable is a string "mrcTrx"

Go to the ******* in commentary to get direct to the point.

I know its not a big deal but I cannot find the answer thank you!

The rest of the code is fine cuz if I a put a value for exemple '05' the code works perfectly

```
Sub GetMun()

          Dim cn As Object
          Dim rs As Object
          Dim intColIndex As Integer

          Dim TargetRange As Range
          Dim mrcMun As String
          Dim mrcTrx As String
          Dim reg As String

          mrcTrx = Val(Range("D2").Value)

            If Len(mrcTrx) < 2 Then

                mrcTrx = "0" + mrcTrx

            End If



            Debug.Print mrcTrx

          Dim totalGP As Integer
          Dim debutRng As String

          totalGP = Sheets("T1").Range("G247").Value

          debutRng = "D" & 250 + totalGP


        mrcMun = "D:\FicheMacro\Mun\PréparationTRX par Munic.mdb"

        'On Error GoTo ErrorGetGPmun

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Set TargetRange = Sheets("T1").Range(debutRng)

        Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & mrcMun
'*******
       Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        rs.Open "SELECT MUNIC FROM Munic_en_MAJ_par_MRC WHERE MRC LIKE ' & mrcTrx & ' ", cn, , , adCmdText


            TargetRange.CopyFromRecordset rs



      Application.ScreenUpdating = True


     rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
     cn.Close
     Set cn = Nothing

   Exit Sub



ErrorGetGPmun:

    MsgBox "Valider le type de trx et l'entête de la T1", vbExclamation, "La Fiche! GP"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the incorrect syntax

```
"SELECT MUNIC FROM Munic_en_MAJ_par_MRC WHERE MRC LIKE '" & mrcTrx & "'"
```

When placing a variable in a string be sure to use `"` and `&` properly in your syntax

Comment: Haha, ironic! I was missing another "&", try it now, it should work :)